# SQL DELETE FROM LEFT JOIN SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-delete

I have this query in SQL Server 2012

```
DELETE FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter] 
WHERE [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter].RecordID IN
            (SELECT TOP(100) *
             FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter] 
             LEFT JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter_Tracking] ON RecordId = Newsletter_Tracking.UserId
             WHERE Newsletter.DateSubscribed < '2010-01-01')
```

The select without the delete works ok. It returns all the rows which are not in left table and which are older than 2010.

And I get this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 100 RecordID` instead of *.

Comment: Use `EXISTS` instead as the error message is suggesting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `IN` operator the subquery must return one single column/value which means you can't use `select *`.

In your case it should most likely be:

```
DELETE FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter] 
WHERE [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter].RecordID IN (
  SELECT [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter].RecordID
  FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter] 
  LEFT JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter_Tracking] ON RecordId = Newsletter_Tracking.UserId
  WHERE Newsletter.DateSubscribed<'2010-01-01'
)
```

Also, using `top` without any `order by` clause will give you a random result - `top` should always by used in conjunction with an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need `RecordId` in the `SELECT`.  An `IN` list only recognizes singleton values, so `SELECT *` generally doesn't work.

```
DELETE FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter] 
WHERE [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter].RecordID IN
(SELECT TOP(100) RecordId
  FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter] LEFT JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[Newsletter_Tracking]
  ON RecordId=Newsletter_Tracking.UserId
  WHERE Newsletter.DateSubscribed<'2010-01-01')
```

Your query does not do this:

> The select without the delete works ok. It returns all the rows which
>   are not in left table and which are older than 2010.

But I suspect you want something more like this:

```
DELETE n
    FROM [DB1].[dbo].Newsletter n
    WHERE n.DateSubscribed < '2010-01-01' AND
          n.RecordID NOT IN (SELECT nt.UserId
                             FROM [dbo].[Newsletter_Tracking] nt
                            );
```

I'm not sure where the `TOP 100` comes in.  Your question doesn't mention it.

Comment: I have added TOP 100 to limit the query, because I made another query which completely blocked the SQL server.

Comment: with your last query I get this error:

DELETE FROM [DB1].[dbo].Newsletter n

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN ALSO USE NOT EXISTS CLAUSE,

```
DELETE n
    FROM [DB1].[dbo].Newsletter n
    WHERE n.DateSubscribed < '2010-01-01' AND
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT nt.UserId
                             FROM [dbo].[Newsletter_Tracking] nt.UserId= n.RecordID
                            );
```